# Прилагательное от "Улан-Удэ"

Tags: словообразование, ономастика

Потребовалось образовать прилагательное от названия столицы Бурятии Улан-Удэ. Я, признаться, зависла. Уланудэшный, что ли?))) Но как-то это не серьезно. И, кстати, прилагательное будет слитно или через дефис писаться?
Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Я требую бана для бегемотуса, ибо заслужил по полной программе. Вместо аргументов и ссылок печатает только устаревшую ересь, обычный набор домашнего демагога.  
Несклоняемое наименование города Улан-Уд**э** образует прилагательное **улан-удэнский**, согласно "Русской грамматике" Института русского языка.

Comment: Я писала о том, что написание горисполкома "Улан-Удэнский" со второй заглавной У - какое-то "подозрительное" (не помню слова - у Дерзкого взяла). И что образование "-удинский" не обязательно от речки Уда. От Удэ тоже вполне возможно: хуанхинский, удэгинский. Второй раз сталкиваюсь с удалением моих комментариев. Кто удалял - не знаю, мне эта опция недоступна. На всякий случай удалила два своих комментария в других темах. Не хочу скандалов. Но больше прошу не удалять. Большое спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Напишите свой внятный ответ на тему рек и речек. Здесь разбирается другой вопрос : о прилагательном от **несклоняемого наименования** города Улан-Удэ. Пишите ответ с подробной аргументацией, **удачи** Вам!

Comment: Просто я не разлогинилась...behemothus! Вы тожем женщина????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Улан-удинский.**

Лопатин даёт как равноправное ещё и **улан-удэнский**, но я бы поостерегся с его использованием. "Не на слуху".

Comment: Я, прочитав вопрос, попыталась сама образовать, у меня получилось именно улан-удэнский.

Comment: Ну поскольку я слышу "улан-удинский" уже лет сорок пять, ухо у меня могло замылиться. Но просто орфоэпия - это не конек Лопатина...
Кабы оно было у Аванесова или еще кого...

Comment: Вполне уже привилось. Но я тоже не сразу приняла.

Answer (score 6):

До 1934 года город назывался Верхнеудинск (при основании - Удинское или Удинский острог). Поэтому окончание **-удинский** позже перешло и в слово *улан-удинский*. Но уже в советское время стал применяться вариант **Улан-удэнский** :

> Машина для средних нагрузок // «Техника - молодежи», 1974  В послевоенные годы паровозы серии СО17 некоторое время строили **Ворошиловградский и Улан-удэнский заводы**.

В последние годы большинство предприятий г.Улан-Удэ и другие организации используют именно данный вариант, через Э, см. ссылку :
[https://www.google.ru/search?q=улан-удэнский](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

[Завод http://www.ulan-ude-vostochnyi.ru/_nw/5/69308135.jpg](http://www.ulan-ude-vostochnyi.ru/_nw/5/69308135.jpg)

Написание советской поры *улан-удинский* более не встречается в Бурятии и не сохраняется в России, и это вполне понятно. Новые времена - новая орфография слов, связанных с национальными топонимами. Следует уважать вполне законный и грамотный выбор жителей Улан-Удэ - уланудэнцев.

> Этнохороним   - уланудэ́нцы, уланудэ́нец, уланудэнка

Выдержка из академического издания **"Русская грамматика" 1980** :

> После гласных в прилагательных, мотивированных несклоняемыми топонимами, этнонимами, фамилиями, аббревиатурами, выступают морфы -йск-, -нск-, -вск- (фонемат. |jс2к|, |нс2к|, |в1с2к|): ханты - хантыйский, Чу - чуйский, Хуло - хулойский, **Улан-Удэ - улан-удэнский**, эрзя - эрзянский, Ришелье - ришельевский, МГУ - эмгеувский (разг.).
>   [СЛОВООБРАЗОВАНИЕ ИМЕН ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ | rusgram.narod.ru](http://rusgram.narod.ru/609-645.html)

Ссылка на ресурс http://pda.gramota.ru/?page=125&action=buro&s=%EF%F0%E8%EB%E0%E3%E0%F2%E5%EB%FC%ED%EE%E5

> Вопрос № 221465
>
> Как пишется прилагательное от названия города Улан-Удэ: улан-удэнский или улан-удинский?
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Оба варианта зафиксированы словарями, но чаще встречается *улан-удэнский*. **В названии района - Улан-Удэнский район.**

Comment: ![Горсовет](http://www.ulan-ude-eg.ru/gorodskoi-sovet/Upolnom_po_pravam_rebenka.jpg)

Comment: Вариант **улан-удэнскиий** практически вытеснил прежнюю "словарную норму". Сегодня она может встретиться разве лишь в виде казуса.  
>29.11.2013  
>Депутаты готовятся к сессии

>Вчера на совместном заседании комитетов **Улан-Удэнского городского Совета** депутаты рассмотрели девять вопросов, планируемых к вынесению на очередную 66 сессию.

http://www.ulan-ude-eg.ru/gorodskoi-sovet/ 

Все реальные современные ссылки имеют написание **улан-удэнский** в абсолютно подавляющем числе примеров.